# KeyUnion by equivalent patterns

Tags: pattern-matching, associations

I have associations whose keys are patterns.  For example,

```
ass1 = <|a_ -> 1, f[] -> 3|>;
ass2 = <|b_ -> 2|>;
```

I would like to construct the union of `ass1` and `ass2` based on keys that may have equivalent patterns.  A straightforward application of `KeyUnion` leads to

```
KeyUnion[{ass1, ass2}]
```

> ```
> {<|a_→1, f[]→3, b_→Missing["KeyAbsent", b_]|>,
>  <|a_→Missing["KeyAbsent", a_], f[]→Missing["KeyAbsent", f[]], b_→2|>}
> ```

with `b_` added to `ass1` and `a_` added to `ass2`.

Since the patterns are equivalent, I'd like the output to be:

> ```
> {<|a_→1, f[]→3|>,
>  <|f[]→Missing["KeyAbsent", f[]], b_→2|>}
> ```

Is it possible to achieve this without compromising the speedup gained in using associations?

Comment: I'm not following why the second association would merge in the way you expect.  I wondering because if I change ass2 to be ass2 = <|a_ -> 2|>; I get something much closer to what you were expecting: {<|a_ -> 1, f[] -> 3|>, <|a_ -> 2, f[] -> Missing["KeyAbsent", f[]]|>}.  I don't know enough to know why the pattern a_ and b_ would merge as you suggest.

Comment: If `KeyUnion` supported `SameTest` we could use ``SameTest -> ("Identical" === Internal`ComparePatterns[##] &)`` I believe, but since it does not this would have to be handled more manually, probably "compromising the speedup gained in using associations" as you put it.  Are you still interested in pursuing that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Unfortunately, I already have the manual implementation just as you describe it.  I am hoping to refactor my code to take advantage of associations.